# How to connect to a specifc node in a mongo replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I use mongo connection uri string to connect to my mongo.

```
mongodb+srv://myname:mypass@mydb.mongodb.net/myDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

This replica set has 4 nodes. I wish to execute my read operation on a specifc node. I have the node url. But I am not sure where I should specify this in the connection uri. I could not find anything regarding this in the [connection-options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-connection-options) for connection uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `readPreferenceTags`. The node that I wanted to connect to had a tag with key `nodeType` and a value `analytics`. So my connection uri had to be modified to

```
mongodb+srv://myname:mypass@mydb.mongodb.net/myDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority&readPreference=secondary&readPreferenceTags=nodeType:ANALYTICS
```

Comment: Your cluster is a MongoDB Atlas cluster.  Atlas uses node tagging for analytics nodes.  A non Atlas cluster (an on-premises cluster) may not have tags.  Suffice it to say connecting to an analytics node in Atlas using the read preference tag is the correct answer.  For an on-prem you can connect directly to a node, but if it is not the primary node it will be read-only and even then you must issue the command rs.secondaryOK() to perform read actions. - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/method/rs.secondaryOk/